# Online SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I am creating a .net project (Windows Forms game) and this project is an online based project run over the internet. In the future, if a shared this game with 2nd person and we both playing in our PC's. He scored 1000 score, when I open game I checked high score status, score is 1000 being shown.

Backend: when I open game, it fetches the latest data from a database and shows it to me.

It means a database is being placed in somewhere and accessed via internet.

Help me out. I want that type of database which can accessed via internet hence I achieve my goal of above project.

Comment: Your question is absolutely horific, but try Mysql which is supported by phpmyadmin

Comment: @Tomm In fairness I think English is probably not their first language

Comment: You can also try Couchdb. And it's IBM hosted version Cloudant. By the way Cloudant has a life time free tier.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a WEB API as access point to your database.

You could structure your backend project like this:

API ( Web Project ) <-> BusinessLayer ( Class Library ) <-> Data Access Layer ( Class Library )

- API: Access point for external app. Trough this you can communicate with your backend with an HTTP Client.
- BL: Here you will apply the (business) logic onto your incoming / outgoing data.
- DAL: This will be the bridge between your logic and your persistence. Here you will define an access point to your database ( e.g. Entity Framework, C# mongodb driver )

This is called a 3 Tier Achitecture.

More about 3 Tier architectures: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/662107/Understand-Tier-Architecture-in-Csharp.

To get started, go here and first build your API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

Then you can correctly adapt the BL / DAL to your needs following either the one I presented you ( 3T ) or any other architecture.

EDIT:

When your project is done, you can publish it on either a provider like Azure.

I recommend doing this in .NET Core actually, as you could deploy it on a Linux which would come out cheaper.